# Automatizacion de selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-3.7, selenium-webdriver

estoy intentando automatizar una subida a una pagina de call center, pero no logro seleccionar el archivo, el HTML es el siguiente:

```
<input type="file" name="FRAM_Buscar$FileUploadArchivos" id="FRAM_Buscar_FileUploadArchivos" style="width:90%;" />
```

Mi Script en Python3 es el siguiente:

```
SelectFile = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FRAM_Buscar_FileUploadArchivos"]')
SelectFile.send_keys('C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Sistemas/Prueba/prueba.txt')
```

pero al iniciar el script resibo el siguiente error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="FRAM_Buscar_FileUploadArchivos"]"}

Comment: Todo parece correcto, puede que el elemento se genere dinámicamente vía javascript, si es ese el caso trata de añadir un tiempo de espera expllícito que espere a que el elemento esté visible: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/267230/15089

Comment: Sigue con el mismo problema, coloque un time.sleep(6) pero sale el mismo error

Comment: Aunque un  time.sleep antes de la llamada a find podría resultar te recomiendo no hacerlo y usa WebDriverWait como se ven en el ejemplo de la respuesta que enlazo arriba y usa un tiempo de espera mayor. Tu código es correcto, pero asumiendo que el input estuviera en el html y no se generara después... Es complicado saber que pasa exactamente cunado no es posible acceder a la url para reproducirlo.

Comment: Sigue el mismo error, El link no lo puedo mostrar por politicas de la empresa, en si el codigo me quedo de la siguiente forma: `SelectFile = WebDriverWait(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FRAM_Buscar_FileUploadArchivos"]'), 20)SelectFile.send_keys('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Sistemas/Prueba/prueba.txt')`

Comment: La sugerencia de @FJSevilla sería asi : 
`SelectFile = WebDriverWait(self.driver,100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="FRAM_Buscar_FileUploadArchivos"]'))
SelectFile.send_keys('foo')`
recuerda importar `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Claro, use esa linea de comando importando expected_conditions, pero todavía no lo detecta