# Continuar Código tras Excepción (Try,Except)

Tags: python, selenium, excepciones

tengo un bloque de programa de python y en un punto del mismo hay veces que me salta una excepción y otras que no, puesto que depende de si aparece un popup en una página web o no.

Me gustaría saber como he de utilizar las secuencias:

```
try:
except:
```

Para conseguir que en caso de que no se encuentre el botón del popup y salte la excepción el código no detenga su ejecución.

Hasta ahora lo que tengo es:
`browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".largeBannerCloser").click()`
que es la instrucción para encontrar el boton de cerrar el popup y hacerle click;

Y por otro lado la excepción que salta es del tipo `NoSuchElementException`

El código que tengo ahora es:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

web_null='https://www.investing.com'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(web_null)
time.sleep(5)

#Esperamos a que aparezca el banner del registro
time.sleep(20)
browser.switch_to.default_content()
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".largeBannerCloser").click()
```

Este es el error que me aparece si intenta hacer click en el la x del banner y este no está presente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/santi/Desktop/DAX - copia - copia (16) - copia - copia/asdfasdf.py", line 44, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".largeBannerCloser").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <i class="popupCloseIcon largeBannerCloser"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y su tiempo

Comment: Coloca el código y el Stack completo. Esa excepción ocurre porque no encuentra esa clase ``largeBannerCloser`` o puede que haya más de una.  Pero sin código completo solo es especulación.

Comment: @FernandoCarraro codigo añadido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que lo que tu quieres hacer es cerrar el banner en caso de que exista. Es decir, tu tienes definida en selenium una serie de pasos que cierran un banner. Sin embargo, si este banner no existe entiendo que no habría que llevar a cabo ninguna acción. En caso de ser así, podrías usar un try except. Primero se ejecutará el código del try. En caso de que salte una excepción al ejecutarlo, en vez de saltarte a ti, será capturada por la sentencia except y llevará a cabo los pasos indicados en ella.

En tu caso, podría hacerse de la siguiente manera:

```py
try:
    time.sleep(20)
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".largeBannerCloser").click()
except:
    pass #Sinónimo de no hacer nada
```

Sin embargo, esta opción capturaría todas las excepciones que pudieran darse. Por lo general, es preferible capturar solo las excepciones que tenemos controladas, ya que si no todas las demás no las llegaríamos a ver y podrían ser problemas reales. Para capturar únicamente tu excepción podrías usar:

```py
try:
    time.sleep(20)
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".largeBannerCloser").click()
except ElementNotInteractableException as exception:
    pass #Sinónimo de no hacer nada
```

Si se diera otra excepción te saltría igual que te salta ahora.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Sí eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias @gontxomde

Answer (score 1):

No te va a servir de nada continuar si el error es el que muestras en la traza completa del final de la pregunta, el problema no es que el PopPup no exista, el problema es que en el momento de hacer click el driver es incapaz de desplazarlo dentro del  Viewport.

La solución es no usar `time.sleep`, de hecho te recomiendo no usarlo nunca con Selenium, el framework ya trae implementados  [tiempos de espera implícitos o explícitos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/267230/15089). En este caso, un tiempo de espera explícito para esperar a que el elemento sea clickable debe resolver el problema:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

web_null='https://www.investing.com'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(web_null)

(WebDriverWait(browser, 300)
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".largeBannerCloser")))
    .click()
    )
```

Ajusta el tiempo de espera a lo que consideres apropiado, de todas formas ten en cuenta que esto no es `time.sleep`, en mi ejemplo espera cinco minutos como máximo, pero si a los diez segundos de ejecutar el código el popup aparece hace el click y continuá la ejecución inmediatamente.

Si el popup no aparece tras el tiempo máximo se lanza una excepción del tipo `TimeoutException` que de ser necesario puedes manejar para reintentarlo  usando un ciclo o continuar la ejecución ignorándolo.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


web_null='https://www.investing.com'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(web_null)

try:
    (WebDriverWait(browser, 300)
        .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".largeBannerCloser")))
        .click()
        )
 except TimeoutException:
     pass
```